# Sorting a big DataFrame with many columns using spark, causes exceeds spark.driver.maxResultSize

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

When running the following query:

```
spark.read.parquet("hdfs:///mydataframe").orderBy('a, 'b, 'timestamp).show(100, false)
```

my spark job fails, with the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 705 tasks (13.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (13.0 GB)

I have about 330 columns, some of them are quite big (arrays of structs etc.), and the DataFrame is about 200GB in total.

I'm using EMR (5.30 , Spark 2.4.5) cluster of 9 x c5.24xlarge machines with driver of m5.xlarge, with default EMR configuration (other than the `spark.driver.maxResultSize` which I increased to 13gb, and using yarn as master).

I can see that with removing columns, it works without exceeding the driver memory, but I'd like to understand if there's another solution other than increasing `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to solve that.
I'd also like to understand, in which manner the driver is involved in the sorting phase, and if there's a way to control that?

Comment: how many partitions does this data is stored ?? try to increase number of partitions using ```repartition``` function.

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: The data is stored within in about 2000 files. I use spark version 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a show write the results down to HDFS/S3. When you do a show on a dataframe the data is sent to the driver.

Comment: The show(100) is a debug run. the real job I'm doing is actually writing results to HDFS/S3, and it has the same issue.

Comment: Could you show the code after the show? Are you running a count?

Comment: There's no code after the show. I'm running it in shell. Also have been running as part of submitted job. Its as simple as the code I've posted.